# Change UILabel insider Header for a collection view

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5

When someone selects a cell in a collection view (about 15 cells)  inside the

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method I am trying to change a label I have placed in the one header by using

```
UICollectionReusableView *headerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"Header" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *headerTitle=(UILabel *)[headerView viewWithTag:1];

    headerTitle.text=@"test";
```

the tag and everything is set correctly, but it does not change.  Any thoughts on where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a header view, so dequeuing one creates another one which is not the one you're trying to change. There is no way to access a header view in a collection view -- there's no headerForSection: method, so you have to change the label through your data source. So, if you just have the one header, then you should have a string property, lets call it headerTitle, that you use to populate the label in the header. So, your implementation of collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath: should look something like this:

```
-(UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    RDReusableHeader *headerView;
    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader){
        headerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"MyView" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        headerView.label.text = self.headerTitle;
    }
    return headerView;
}
```

Then in didSelectItemAtIndexPath:, assign a new value to that property and call reloadData on the collection view.

```
    self.headerTitle = @"This is the New Tilte";
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
```